# include a variable in an OCI8 insert statement

Tags: ruby, oracle, insert, oci8

I'm having a hard time using variables in my oci8 insert statement.

```
CSV.foreach('C:/csv_test.csv') do |row|
gender = row[0]
name = row[1]
year = row[2]
command = 'INSERT INTO CSV_TEST VALUES('+gender+','+name+','+year+')'
conn.exec(command)
end
```

i made sure that everything works fine. Gender, name and year contain my data and the insert works just fine. But i can't call the gender, name and year variables in my insert statement.
The error I'm receiving is:

```
column not allowed here
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gender` and `name` must be quoted with `'` inside SQL string.

Comment: also you should specify what columns you want to insert, otherwise your insert will break as soon as a new column is added to your table or the columns get reordered.

Comment: Could you please be more specific Egor, i tried your solution but I'm not sure I got it right.

Comment: @user3415827 - Your `command` value must look like `INSERT INTO CSV_TEST VALUES('M','John',2014)` after string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to do this is using bindvariables. This will eliminate any escaping bugs and security flaws.

Oracle has a [decent ruby tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/opensrclang/rubyrails/rubyrails.htm) for working with ruby. Unfortunately I don't have Oracle installed, so I can't test this this. I'm guessing the following will work though:

```
cursor = conn.parse('INSERT INTO CSV_TEST VALUES(:gender,:name,:year)')
cursor.bind_param(1,String)
cursor.bind_param(2,String)
cursor.bind_param(3,Fixnum) 
CSV.foreach('C:/csv_test.csv') do |row|
    gender = row[0]
    name = row[1]
    year = row[2]
    cursor[1] = gender
    cursor[2] = name
    cursor[3] = year.to_i
    cursor.exec  
end
```